# AS3 manipulation of multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array

good day :)

Why is it that when i edit the `hold:Array`, the `array:Array` also gets editted?

To give an example:

```
function func(2, 2) { //x, y COORDINATE
   var hold = array[2]; //GET COLUMN OF ARRAY
   hold[2] = 2;         //SET hold[x] to 2
   trace(array[2][2])   //SAME AS hold[x] *but i didn't change array[x]'s value!*
}
```

**STEP BY STEP analysis**

*array[] looks like this (for example):*

```
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1
```

*Thus, `var hold = array[y]`:* (where y=2)

```
1,1,1,1
```

*and `hold[x] = 2`* (where x=2)

```
1,2,1,1
```

*Now, tracing `array[y][x]`* (where y=2, x=2)

```
1,2,1,1
```

*But `array[2][2]` should be `1,1,1,1`, because we didn't edit it's value!*

**Question**
Why does `array[]` get edited when i only edited `hold[]`

Comment: Sorry, i had some mistakes please re read it!

Comment: It's an example, but i'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because arrays (typeof will give Object) are passed by reference. To copy its values you need to [**clone an array in ActionScript**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html).

[Here's an explanation of this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000049.html) for ActionScript 2.0 (which also applies to ActionScript 3.0 but I couldn't find the version of this article for the latter).

Comment: Thanks for the reference just what i needed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, arrays are stored against variables as a *reference*. This means that when you create your array `array` and then store it in `hold` to create a 2D array, you're simply storing a reference to `array` within `hold`.

For example, you would expect that if you stored a Sprite within an array and then edited that Sprite's values, that you would see those changes from anywhere else you've referenced the Sprite. This is the same for arrays.

```
var array:Array = [];
var another:Array = [];
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

array.push(sprite);
another.push(sprite);

array[0].x = 10;
trace(another[0].x); // Also 10.
```

If you don't want this behaviour, you can use `.slice()` or `.concat()` to make a shallow clone of an array:

```
array.push(hold.slice()); // or
array.push(hold.concat());
```

Comment: [(…) In a shallow copy, if the original array has elements that are objects, only the references to the objects are copied rather than the objects themselves. The copy points to the same objects as the original does. Any changes made to the objects are reflected in both arrays.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee7.html)

Comment: @inhan That is correct, I'm not sure what you're trying to say? In the case of the OP also, that is not a concern because all the values are primitives (Numbers, Booleans or Strings) which will be cloned.

Comment: Just wanted to make it clear for the OP (and potential others looking for a similar solution) that using this method will not work as expected in certain circumstances. So it was just a critical addition to your post, nothing else.

Comment: @inhan Sure, although if I was making a copy of an array I would naturally expect it to have the original references anyway, I think a deep copy is only expected in special circumstances. Thanks though.